# How to set stderr for daemon C++

Tags: c++, linux

I am using some third party library which is using stderr to print error and it don't gives any callback for logging. 
I am using linux `daemon` call to create daemon of the process.

Is there a way I can set stderr to file after daemon call ?

Comment: If that third party library is free software, you could patch its source code to use `syslog` and publish the patch to push it upstream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `open` system call to open the file, then do this: `dup2(filefd, 2)`. That will set `stderr` to the opened file. You can then `close(filefd)`. You can do the `open` before calling `daemon`, but I wouldn't recommend the `dup2` and subsequent `close` until after calling `daemon`.

Answer (score 2):

In the code using the third party library, you can "reroute" the stderr stream.
e.g. something like:

```
std::ofstream outputFileStream;
outputFileStream.open ("outputfile.txt");

std::streambuf * yourStreamBuffer = outputFileStream.rdbuf();
std::cerr.rdbuf(yourStreamBuffer);

std::cerr << "Ends up in the file, not std::cerr!";

outputFileStream.close();
```

Comment: Well, this relies on the library faithfully using `cerr`. Since this question has the `linux` tag, I think an OS specific solution that actually covers all your bases no matter what the errant library does is the way to go.